# c# Is this a safe way for a login form?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, sql-injection, sqlparameter

```
                myConnection.Open();
            myString = textBox2.Text;
            myPass = textBox1.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Connection established!", "Succes!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            using (MySqlCommand looking = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM `users` WHERE username LIKE @User AND password LIKE @password", myConnection))
            {
                looking.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("User", myString));
                looking.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("password", myPass));
                MySqlDataReader readData = looking.ExecuteReader(); 

                while(readData.Read()) 
                {
                    login = true;
                }
if (login)
   MessageBox.Show("Succes!");
}
```

Hi! I wonder if the code above is a safe way for a login form? Is it possible to do a SQL injection here?

Also how do I save my connectionstring safely? I've been looking around but I don't know the best option..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe for SQL Injection, **but** you should compare for exact match instead of using `LIKE` for username and password.

```
"Select * FROM `users` WHERE username = @User AND password = @password"
```

Apart from safety, if you are only interested in knowing if the records exists or not, then use `COUNT` and get the results using `ExecuteScalar` instead of select all the columns.

```
"Select COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE username = @User AND password = @password"
```

and get the results as:

```
int count = (int) looking.ExecuteScalar();
if(count > 0)
{
   //found
}
```

Comment: Okey thank you! So if I allways use Parameters will it allways be SQL injection safe?

Comment: @GustavPSvensson, Yes.

Comment: Hah! Great, thank you! And do you know any good way of saving my connectionstring safely?

Comment: @GustavPSvensson, it depends on the type of application you are targeting but in general see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164054.aspx)

Comment: This is an application that people will use to sign into the database and they will retrive some information from the database when they are logged in.